# how to depict a network with a legend

Tags: graphs-and-networks, legending

Because my network nodes have real world names more than a few characters long, I'd like to label them with a shortcut, e.g., n1, n2, n3, ..., and put a legend on the side something like this: n1 - fooLongName, n2 - barLongName, n3 - bazLongName.

Any ideas for how to do this?

Comment: Thanks to kguler for the answer below. Unfortunately I should have been more specific in my question. What I have is a directed network. My fiddling to fit the code structure below with GraphPlot hasn't worked. But I confess to having only tried quick/dirty, not really paying my dues.

Answer (score 7):

```
labels = Table[i -> Style[Subscript[v, i], 20], {i, 3}]
names = Table[i -> "longname_" <> "v_" <> ToString@i, {i, 3}];
colors = {1 -> Blue, 2 -> Red, 3 -> Green}; 

legend = SwatchLegend[Last /@ colors, 
      Row[{#[[1]], ": ", #[[2]]}] & /@ Transpose[{labels, names}][[All, All, -1]],
      LegendMarkers -> "Bubble"];
```

You can use `Legended`, `Epilog` or `Row` to add legends to a `Graph`:

```
Legended[Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3,  3 <-> 1},  VertexSize -> 0.1,
                VertexStyle -> colors, VertexLabels -> labels, ImagePadding -> 20], 
         legend]
```

[image]

```
Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1},
    VertexStyle -> colors, VertexSize -> 0.1, VertexLabels -> labels, 
    ImagePadding -> 20, 
 Epilog -> Inset[legend, {.75, .75}]]
```

[image]

```
Row[{Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, VertexStyle -> colors, VertexSize -> 0.1, 
            VertexLabels -> labels, ImagePadding -> 20, ImageSize -> 300], 
    legend}]
```

[image]